# Spring roo don't create finder

Tags: spring-roo

Does anyone know, why Spring roo don't create finder?
I'm trying to create finder for example:

```
finder add --finderName findAmenitysByDescription
```

But Roo added only

```
finders = { "findAmenitysByDescription" }
```

into a class `Amenity` without creating `.aj` file

Does anyone have suggestions for this problem?

Comment: Do you use Eclipse? Does `*.aj` file present in a file system?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the Roo command `finder list` to get the finder name you wanted to add?